# How to create dynamic drupal 7 taxonomy views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have to create 1 view using taxonomy.

Let's take the example i have 8 categories: cricket, football, tennis, swimming.

I have to show this each category with their 5 latest articles.

Thew views should display database like

Cricket

1. Article
2. Article 2

Football

1. Article
2. Article 2

Like this all 8 categories with grid layout and 4 categories in row.

right now what i am doing is creating 8 different views and showing on 1 page.

But this create issue when i am adding new category.

So it's dynamic view can help or i have to write code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a single view to display articles and then require that they have a relationship to your taxonomy vocabulary.

You can the group the articles by their taxonomy terms to list them in the way you are looking to.

Comment: I tried like this i create view with 2 relation ship 1 is with taxonomy and second with root taxonomy but showing me exact result which i expected but now problem is different. View preview is working but when i save and run the page it's not working.